Cross Section Formula and Delta Function Identity (Eq 4.77 in Peskin & Schroeder QFT)
In the book, while deriving the cross section formula for particles A and B, a Dirac delta appears in Eq 4.77:
\begin{align}
\int d\bar{k}^z_A \, \delta\left.
\left(
\sqrt{(\bar{k}^\perp_A)^2+(\bar{k}^z_A)^2+m^2_A} + \sqrt{(\bar{k}^\perp_B)^2+(k^z_A+k^z_B - \bar{k}^z_A)^2+m^2_B}
\\
-\sqrt{(k^\perp_A)^2+(k^z_A)^2+m^2_A}
-\sqrt{(k^\perp_B)^2+(k^z_B)^2+m^2_B}
\right)
\right\vert_{\bar{k}^\perp_A=k^\perp_A,\bar{k}^\perp_B=k^\perp_B}
=
\frac{1}{\left\vert\frac{\bar{k}^z_A}{\bar{E}_A}-\frac{\bar{k}^z_B}{\bar{E}_B}\right\vert}.
\end{align}
Because of the Dirca delta, this result comes together with a constraint
\begin{equation}
\bar{k}^z_A=k^z_A.
\end{equation}
In Eq 4.78 on the next page, this is used to exchange the barred variables in terms of unbarred ones. For example,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{E_A\bar{E}_A}}\phi_A(\vec{k}_A)\phi^\star_A(\vec{\bar{k}}_A)
=
\frac{\vert\phi_A(\vec{k}_A)\vert^2}{E_A}.
\end{equation}
I know how to deal with a composition of Dirac delta with a function, and it is clear that the function has a zero at $\bar{k}^z_A=k^z_A$.
But what guarantees that it has only one zero?
By manipulating the function, we can get a quadratic equation of $\bar{k}^z_A$. There is one another solution different to $k^z_A$. Let's denote the second solution by $K$. Then, the first equation above should give
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\left\vert\frac{\bar{k}^z_A}{\bar{E}_A}-\frac{k^z_A+k^z_B-\bar{k}^z_A}{\bar{E}_B}\right\vert} \times \left( \bar{k}^z_A = k^z_A\right)
+
\frac{1}{\left\vert\frac{\bar{k}^z_A}{\bar{E}_A}-\frac{k^z_A+k^z_B-\bar{k}^z_A}{\bar{E}_B}\right\vert}\times \left( \bar{k}^z_A =K \right).
\end{align}
That is, the constraints are not given as independent options. They are summed together, so it is impossible to choose one of them as we want. But as you can see in Eq 4.78, the authors take only one solution $\bar{k}^z_A=k^z_A$.
Why do we take only one solution $\bar{k}^z_A=k^z_A$?

What’s stopping you from doing exactly what you said in the last line? That’ll give you the answer right away

@Prahar The result must be like $\frac{1}{\textrm{blahblah}} \delta (\bar{k}^z_A-k^z_A) + \frac{1}{\textrm{blahblah}} \delta(\bar{k}^z_A-\textrm{2nd solution})$. That is, two deltas are not given as two independent options but summed together. So, I think we should not pick only one of them as we like.
